# Hanging indents in bibliography

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, indentation, pandoc

I can't imagine this isn't covered elsewhere, but for the life of my I can't find it. (Forgive me, I'm very new to LaTeX.)

I'm running `pandoc` to generate PDFs based on a markdown document, but right now my bibliography is being formatted just like another other paragraph: leading indent, no space between entries. I'd like to format it with hanging indents and a slight space between sections. It seems like that should be default behavior, but even when I strip away the LaTeX template to bare bones, I can't get the bibliography to behave properly.

I'm running the `memoir` class, and using the `chicago-fullnotes-bibliography` style. I'm wondering if there's either a way to change default bibliography behavior, or hack a different indent pattern for that section of the document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what 'chicago-fullnotes-bibliography' is, but if it is based on `biblatex`, the following lengths are probably what you want to redefine to your liking:

```
\setlength{\bibhang}{11pt}% the hanging indent
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{6pt}% the separation b/w basic items
\setlength{\bibinitsep}{\baselineskip}% insert blank line between different initial letters
```

These will work with the `memoir` class; change the lengths to suit your needs.

If you are not using `biblatex`, but need to follow the Chicago style, I recommend you switch sooner rather than later to `biblatex` and `biber`, and use the `biblatex-chicago` contributed style.  It implements CMS 16th ed., and is under active development.  The author is also responsive to feedback about potential problems.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because that definitely should fix it, but unfortunately I'm realizing that `pandoc` doesn't actually let the LaTeX template do much with the bibliography. `chicago-fullnotes-bibliography` is a CSL style, and `pandoc` does all the bibliography formatting as per its specifications. (Unfortuately, it doesn't seem to be responding to those, either--but that's a question for the `pandoc` listserve.) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Indeed.  There is nothing in the .csl that gives formatting directives about the bibliography.  I guess that makes sense, but the Chicago style can be pretty picky about things.  As for `pandoc`, my limited experience suggested that it couldn't (then; yet?) handle all of `biblatex`'s capabilities.  (But I'm an `emacs` user, so `org-mode` would be my starting point for simple documents; and of course real `LaTeX` when I want to write something complicated....)

Comment: Brain, I think pandoc leaves most of the bibliography work to LaTeX (instead of doing it itself) if you supply the `--biblatex` switch.

Answer (score 3):

The [answer provided by @jon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57684/144087) just gives me an error message.

But I found the following workaround to be working nicely. If your bibliography should appear at the end of the document (the default), just add the following lines at the very end of the Markdown document:

```tex
\noindent
\vspace{-2em}
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{15pt}
```

However, if you're manually defining the position of the bibliography (using the tag `<div id="refs"></div>`), you have to wrap the above lines and the `<div>` tag in a Latex group to limit the formatting changes to the bibliography only:

```tex
\begingroup
\noindent
\vspace{-2em}
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{15pt}

<div id="refs"></div>

\endgroup
```

Explanation of the commands:

- `\setlength{\parindent}` and `\setlength{\leftskip}` define the hanging indentation of the bibiography entries.
- `\setlength{\parskip}` defines the spacing between bibliography entries.
- `\noindent` is needed in order to *also* have the very first bibliography entry correctly hanging indented.
- `\vspace{-2em}` reduces the vertical spacing between the bibliography and the last paragraph before it (because `\noindent` adds a blank paragraph).

source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pandoc-discuss/4SKA5E11rO4/fDGiNSOsIMkJ

Comment: Welcome, this does seem ro be a very strange answer. Can you extend it so people can understand it better?

Comment: @Johannes_B I tried my best; I'm a complete (La)Tex novice, it's the best I can provide :)

Answer (score 2):

(I don't have the reputation to simply make this a comment, but I also wanted to concatenate both replies above for future googlers like me)

Pandoc’s built-in bibliography formatting uses [citeproc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc) to generate the “bibliography.” That is, although it reads a `.bib` file and generates a `.pdf` through an engine like XeLaTeX, it never actually calls biber, etc.

If you output a pandoc-generated bibliography to a `.tex` file, you get something like this at the very end:

```
\hypertarget{refs}{}
\leavevmode\hypertarget{ref-nightwood}{}%
Barnes, Djuna. 1936. \emph{Nightwood}. New York: New Directions.

\leavevmode\hypertarget{ref-fama_melancholic_2014}{}%
Fama, Katherine A. ``Melancholic Remedies: Djuna Barnes's
\emph{Nightwood} as Narrative Theory.'' \emph{Journal of Modern
Literature} 37, no. 2 (2014): 39--58.
\url{https://doi.org/10.2979/jmodelite.37.2.39}.
```

As a result, [@jon’s solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57684/120921) cannot fix the inherent problem in Pandoc, because the resulting output is not marked in such a way to react to something like `\bibhang`.

Hence the “easiest” solution is to force a change in formatting, akin to what [@salim-b suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392812/120921).

A similar solution to the one offered is to install [pandoc-citeproc-preamble](https://github.com/spwhitton/pandoc-citeproc-preamble), which inserts a short `.tex` file before where the bibliography would be created. The basic version of that is:

```
\section*{References}
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
\singlespacing
\small
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
\vspace*{-0.4in}
\noindent
```

In my own practice (as indicated in the template [simple-essay](https://github.com/plain-plain-text/simple-essay)), I simply append a file similar to the quoted bit above when summoning Pandoc:

```
pandoc -sr markdown+yaml_metadata_block+citations \
  --pdf-engine=xelatex --template=template.tex \
  --filter pandoc-citeproc \
  ./metadata.yml ./tmp/main.md ./bibliography-preamble.tex \
  -o output.pdf
```

Pandoc *does* have a feature, however, to convert its citation syntax into BibLaTeX commands. Adding the flag `--biblatex` at compile time will fill the resulting `.tex` file with all the `\autocite`s and so on one would want. As the documentation clearly notes, however:

> This option is not for use with the pandoc-citeproc filter or with PDF output. It is intended for use in producing a LaTeX file that can be processed with bibtex or biber.

In that case, the full incantation is something like:

```
pandoc -sr markdown+yaml_metadata_block+citations \
  --biblatex ./metadata.yml ./tmp/main.md \
  -o output.tex ; xelatex output.tex ; biber output ; xelatex output.tex ; xelatex output.tex
```

And, in fact, this is, I believe, the solution I will personally use moving forward. I get a properly formatted bibliography using a tool reacting properly/semantically to its environment, not the kind of kludge that Citeproc produces.

Comment: This is the most useful and informative answer for those using pandoc-citeproc.